# Is it a good idea to use table inheritance just to not repeat code?

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 models (tables) that have half of their attributes (columns) exactly the same (same data types). Is it ok to use Postgres table inheritance just to avoid retyping those fields in each model (table)?

example fields that could be "shared":

```
title
subtitle
slug
description
seoTile
seoDescription
...
```

Comment: A search for "SQL supertype / subtype" should get you going.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider normalizing your data: putting the common set of data into its own table and referencing that from the others.

Comment: Yes I thought about it but then I can't take advantage of foreign keys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Postgres inheritance comes with a number of caveats that are well documented in the manual, so you should probably read up on them prior to moving forward.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html

The short short version is, in essence: more often than not you'll want to avoid using table inheritance, unless you're looking into partitioning a large table.